# Spring Integration Email using IMAP Office 365

Tags: email, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

We are planning to use **[Spring Integration Mail Support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mail.html#mail)** with Office365 using IMAP however, it is not working as intended and we are getting authentication failed errors:

```
2022-12-19 08:45:12.257 ERROR --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.i.h.LoggingHandler                   : org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: failure occurred while polling for mail; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed.
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.MailReceivingMessageSource.doReceive(MailReceivingMessageSource.java:74)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractMessageSource.receive(AbstractMessageSource.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:212)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:444)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:413)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$4(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:348)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$5(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:341)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed.
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:708)
```

**Note**: It is working fine using GMAIL via App password but for Office365 its not. Here is the sample bean we have:

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow iMapIntegrationFlow(
            // Remove for brevity
    ) {
        log.info("[Email Integration] Creating Spring Integration Flow Bean");
        var pollerSpec = Pollers
                .fixedRate(5000)
                .maxMessagesPerPoll(1);
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Mail.imapInboundAdapter("imap://username%40domain:PASSWORD@outlook.office365.com:993/INBOX")
                                .javaMailProperties(myJavaMailProperties)
                                .simpleContent(true)
                                .maxFetchSize(1),
                        e -> e.poller(pollerSpec))
                .transform(myTransformer)
                .handle(myHandler)
                .get();
    }
```

Below are my Java Mail properties:

```
mail.imap.port=993
mail.imaps.ssl.enable=true
mail.debug=true
```

Any help for the following questions are highly appreciated:

1. Is there something missing/incorrect in our config?
2. Is this basic authentication deprecation by MS causing the issue? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online
3. If item#2 is true then is there a documented way in Spring Integration Mail to support OAuth2?

Comment: See here:https://javaee.github.io/javamail/OAuth2. You are probably missing to set `mail.imap.sasl.mechanisms=XOAUTH2` JavaMail property. And pay attention that `password` must be an `oauth2_access_token` instead.

Comment: The `jakarta.mail.Authenticator` may help to obtain that OAuth token dynamically when session is created.

Comment: Thank you @ArtemBilan - I will take a look into it but would be great if I could have a sample of how to obtain token dynamically via `jakarta.mail.Authenticator`? Also, if I inject `IntegrationFlow ` as a bean then what will be the implications in case the access token has expired (e.g., 1 hour) would this authenticator obtain a new access token automatically? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with OAuth, but I believe this `Authenticator` can be implemented the way that it refreshes a token whenever it is requested and indeed expired. See its Javadocs for more info.